# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, sidekiq

I've a repeatedly `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` with Sidekiq in Heroku. here is the full error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.008 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

- I'm using 1 dyno for Sidekiq with size `Performance L`, with a concurrency of `15`
- For the web server, I'm using `1` dyno with `2` puma workers and `15` threads each so the total is (1 * 2 * 15  = 30).
- My DB pool size is `20` (I'm using `Standard-0` postgres which have maximum 120 connections).

So how am I getting this error while the connection pool size is greater than the maximum number of connection that could be used? total of (15 + 40 = 45) from 120

here is my configs files:

### - `condig/sidekiq.yml`

```
    concurrency: 15
    :queues:
      - myapp
```

### - `condig/inititalizers/sidekiq.rb`

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] } if ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"].present?

  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ServerMiddleware, expiration: 30.minutes
  end
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] } if ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"].present?
end

if Rails.env.production?
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] }
  end
end

Sidekiq.default_worker_options = {
  queue: "myapp",
  backtrace: true,
  retry: false
}
```

### - `config/puma`

```
workers Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV["RAILS_MAX_THREADS"] || 15)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV["PORT"]     || 3000
environment ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

### - `database.yml`

```
production:
  pool: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case is the puma vs database config, your puma server will try to spawn 30 threads but the config of the database pool wich is shared for all of them, is set to just 20 connections (it ignores that your database can handle 120 just uses what is in the configuration), so 10 puma threads will hit that error constantly.

Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/issues/42#issuecomment-72244263) shows how Active Record can release connections properly after the `work()` method had completed. It describes an issue with sneakers, but can be used for Sidekiq too, since it is the Active Record issue.

```
def work(msg)
  id = JSON.parse(msg)['id']
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    user = User.find(id)
    user.name="Homer Simpson"
    user.save
  end
  ack!
end
```